# Access Form / VBA: Concatenated Field Name

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba

I created a Form in Access, and within this form there is a button which will allow the user to insert a record into a table ("Tbl")

The format of this table is:
Report1_Field1
Report1_Field2
Report2_Field1
Report2_Field2 (and so on)

The Form will ask the user to:
- Select the report name ("ReportName"); which could be "Report1" or "Report2"
- Input a value for Field1 and Field2

The VBA code behind the button is as follows:

```
Private Sub ButtonUpdate
Dim NameReport as String
Dim FirstField as String
Dim SecondField as String

NameReport = ReportName
FirstField = ReportName & "_Field1"
SecondField = ReportName & "_Field2"

DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl (FirstField, SecondField) VALUES (Field1, Field2)"

End Sub
```

I am however getting the Run-Time error 3127: The INSERT INTO statement contains the following unknown field name: 'FirstField'. Make sure you have typed the name correctly, and try the operations again.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL string is reading "FirstField" and "SecondField" as literal text instead of using your variables. Try this:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tbl (" & FirstField & ", " & SecondField & ") VALUES (Field1, Field2)"
```